MenuBarExtra does not update it's view in the real time
I am trying to create a MenuBarExtra with dynamic content, but the content does not get updated
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text(text) // --------- 1
            TextField("", text: $text)
        }

        MenuBarExtra("A") {
            Text(text) // --------- 2
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}


In the code above, the Text[1] gets updated in the real time but the Text[2] does not update after the first appearance of MenuBarExtra

SwiftUI doesn't seem to correctly identify the dependencies of the menu bar extra. This might be a SwiftUI bug.
You can work around this by passing a @Binding to a wrapper view.
@State var text = ""

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        Text(text)
        TextField("", text: $text)
    }

    MenuBarExtra("A") {
        Wrapper(text: $text)
    }
    .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
}

struct Wrapper: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
    }
}

This also works if you pass a ObservableObject to a @ObservedObject, or if you pass a @Observable instance.

Thanks @Sweeper. It works as expected
